# zoomla to wordpress exportor giving error?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I am getting this error while installing plugin present on site
http://www.bin-co.com/blog/2009/07/export-to-wordpress-joomla-plugin/

```
JFolder::create: Could not create directory
Component Install: Failed to create directory.: "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Joomla/components/com_wordpressexport"
Install Component Error
```

plz help
thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already use this component. So Please properly uninstall `"com_wordpressexport`" then try it.